# requirejs errors with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

Hi  I have some errors with jquery,  what i'm trying to do is pull in what is prebid split into different files and place a few lines of code on a site, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://adops.adysis.com/pubYYYYY/app/slotsonpage.js" > 
</script><
<footerbid1>
<script  data-main="https://adops.adysis.com/pubYYYYY/app.js" 
src="https://adops.adysis.com/pubYYYYY/require-min.js"></script>
</footerbid1>
```

its works with the slotspage.js at the top of the site and the footerbid1 at the bottom of the site, but its ridiculously slow to load the ads,  so when i move the footerbid1 to the top of the page,  i get some jquery errors, there are loads of jquery files being loaded on site, which I have no control over and cant move etc.  is there any simple way around this?

these are the errors it throws:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me that you are trying to call jquery functions before the jquery is loaded. You may have to move your "jquery include" to an area in your application to ensure it is loaded before its called.

Comment: i'm not calling jquery at all, with what im doing with requirejs,  not that i know of anyway.  That line that has jquery.js at the end, which i blanked out the folder name, aint being called by me

Comment: @DavidStanton seems that is also the problem you are not using jquery where's requirejs library is expecting jQuery inside loaded in your document. try including jQuery before that script.

Comment: i think i put this info above,  if i move my script below where jquery is on the site, it works, but then makes ad load painfully slow, so i need to get my scripts up in the head of the site and eradicate the jquery errors

Comment: i've found this in requirejs file, can it juts be taken out?    define.amd = {
            jQuery: !0
        },

Comment: My guess is that the speed may be another issue. You can't call functions that require jquery before it is loaded. I would look into caching to increase the speed. Are you loading the add from a third party?